# How to Select and override values from MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql

We have a simple MySql table which stores settings for our app.  We normally use our code to just select all the data and do the following:-

Override values based on a given Environment.  This works fine, as the code would take care of replacing values based on env and create an object with correct values, but now thinking of just pushing the job to the MySql db.

Table

```
| SettingName | SettingValue   | Environment |
| ------------|----------------|-------------|
| ApiUrl      | api1.xxx.com   | Dev         |
| ApiUrl      | api2.xxx.com   | Test        |
| ApiUrl      | api3.xxx.com   | Live        |
| SomeSetting | 0              | Test        |
| SomeSetting | 1              | Live        |
```

In some cases we may have Settings for each Enviroment in others we have just 2.
There will always be at least 2 Test/Live.

I would like to achieve the following:
Given 2 Environments like Dev as the current and Test as the fallback I want a table that will give me Dev setting if it exists or fallback to Test if it does not.

I have tried the following:-

```
SET @defaultEnv = 'Test'; //Fallback if settings don't exist for @env
SET @env = 'Live';
SELECT s.SettingName,IFNULL(filter.SettingValue,s.SettingValue) as SettingValue 
                                FROM Settings AS s
                                LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Settings WHERE Environment=@env) AS filter ON filter.SettingName = s.SettingName
                                WHERE s.Environment = @defaultEnv;
```

This does not seem to bring in correct values as required based on the correct Environment.

Do I need a CASE statement or any other way?

Comment: "This works fine but now thinking of just pushing the job to the MySql db." what do you mean by this? "This seemed to work but because Test is not NULL in some cases it will use the test value instead of Live." and this? Can you clarify what is or isn't working?

Comment: Have edited this to basically say that using our code (c#) we can get all this to work by pulling values and using code to replace as required. But the db query I am trying does not work correcly as it seems to pull wrong settings.

Comment: I tried testing with your example data and it looks like it works. Cf. https://dbfiddle.uk/TwTRVl_y Can you explain why this doesn't return the correct values based on the preferred environment? Can you produce another dbfiddle demo that shows how the result is wrong?

Comment: Same with this fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cjVfQJYWrXCR81FRrMr7V1/1 that shows how a `Test` value is used if `Live` is null (api2).

Comment: To be clear in this case Live should be api3 not api2. If you set env to live I ant api3 and this is why I think the IFNULL is not the right choice and looking for alternative.

Comment: The tests that I ran return api3. Same for the test run by WOUNDEDStevenJones. Please look at the dbfiddle demos.

Comment: Appreciate both I will take a look for me the result was not changing.  So will check what is wrong at my end.

Comment: Can you add an additional join condition on the environment, so that you only match the setting for the specific environment or the fallback environment if it doesn't exist.

Comment: `SET @defaultEnv = 'Test'; 
SET @env = 'Live';

SELECT s.SettingName, COALESCE(envSetting.SettingValue, fallbackSetting.SettingValue) AS SettingValue
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT SettingName FROM Settings WHERE Environment IN (@defaultEnv, @env)
) AS s
LEFT JOIN Settings AS envSetting ON envSetting.SettingName = s.SettingName AND envSetting.Environment = @env
LEFT JOIN Settings AS fallbackSetting ON fallbackSetting.SettingName = s.SettingName AND fallbackSetting.Environment = @defaultEnv
WHERE envSetting.SettingValue IS NOT NULL OR fallbackSetting.SettingValue IS NOT NULL;`

Comment: As for @WOUNDEDStevenJones and Biil comments the query works.  It seems the issue was at my end with the sql server not executing the variables.